# Syncfusion filters are not working with Angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, syncfusion

we are using Syncfusion UI for our application but the filters, sortings are not working.

Please find below stackblitz link to get the issue details

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-andvzf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The feature modules are not injected in your sample. To use paging feature, you need to inject the `PageService` in the providers section.

```
import { GridModule, FilterService, PageService, SortService } from '@syncfusion/ej2-angular-grids';
@NgModule({
   imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, GridModule],
   declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent ],
   bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
   providers: [FilterService, PageService, SortService]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Modified: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zudzuo?file=src/app/app.module.ts

For available feature modules, please look at the below link.

https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/grid/module/

https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/grid/getting-started/#module-injection